# Getting following error while provisioning AD account in Sailpoint

Tags: active-directory, provisioning, sailpoint

I am getting following error while provisioning AD Account to user.

```
An unexpected error occurred: Exception evaluating rule: Cloud Account Attribute Transform sailpoint.tools.GeneralException: The application script threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error running rule transform:sailpoint.tools.GeneralException: The application script threw an exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Exception: Unable to contact connector to generate unique value and is not retry-able. Action:UniqueAccountIdValidator: Calling getObject for objectType 'account' using id 'CN=Test1,OU=YOURCONTAINER, DC=YOURDOMAIN' and options '{cloudConfigOverrides={aggregateTimeout=30, disablePooling=true, timeout=30}}' on source 'Active Directory Test [source]'. Exception: sailpoint.connector.ConnectorException: Failed to find connection settings for the dc=yourdomain BSF info: Create Unique Account ID at line: 0 column: columnNo BSF info: Cloud Account Attribute Transform at line: 0 column: columnNo
```

Comment: "Failed to find connection settings for the dc=yourdomain", sounds like you haven't fully configured your AD connector

Comment: Actually added all the details and configuration also aggregation works correctly. Not sure what is missing.

Comment: This looks like an IdentityNow (could just be a transform in IIQ, but you didn't say so just guessing) problem - also can you please include the IQService logs? (Please set them at 2 so we can get details)